# SQL join without data loss

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a select that naturally joins 2 tables. Afer joining table A with table B the new temporary table C doesn't contain the row of table A if the primary key of this row is not used in any rows of table B. I understand why that happens, but I want the row also in table C.

Example

```
select deptno, dname, loc, count(deptno) empcount, round(avg(sal),2) avgsal
from dept natural join emp
group by deptno, dname, loc
```

Result:

```
    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC             EMPCOUNT     AVGSAL
---------- -------------- ------------- ---------- ----------
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS                 5       2175 
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK               3    2916.67 
        30 SALES          CHICAGO                6    1566.67
```

What I want:

```
    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC             EMPCOUNT     AVGSAL
---------- -------------- ------------- ---------- ----------
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS                 5       2175 
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK               3    2916.67 
        30 SALES          CHICAGO                6    1566.67 
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON                 0          0
```

Table dept (A):

```
    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC         
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK      
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS        
        30 SALES          CHICAGO       
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Table emp (B):

```
     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20 
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300         30 
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500         30 
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20 
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400         30 
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850                    30 
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450                    10 
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000                    20 
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000                    10 
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0         30 
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100                    20 
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950                    30 
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000                    20 
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300                    10
```

Comment: Don't use natural joins. Specify joins explicitly to avoid future pain.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp You're right, I don't think I'll change anything on these tables, but on other projects it might be problematic. I'll change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot, it was the outer join I was looking for.
So here's the sql command that deliveres the result I was looking for:

SQL99-Syntax:

```
select deptno, dname, loc, nvl(ecount,0) empcount, nvl(round(avg(sal),2),0) avgsal
from dept left join emp using(deptno)
  left join (select deptno, count(deptno) ecount
             from emp
             group by deptno) using(deptno)
group by deptno, dname, loc, ecount
```

Standard SQL-Syntax:

```
select d.deptno, d.dname, d.loc, nvl(n.ecount,0) empcount, nvl(round(avg(e.sal),2),0) avgsal
from dept d, emp e, (select deptno, count(deptno) ecount
                     from emp
                     group by deptno) n
where d.deptno = e.deptno (+)
and n.deptno (+) = e.deptno
group by d.deptno, d.dname, d.loc, n.ecount
```

The column empcount is 0 if there are no employees in the department. In the other solutions it was 1 because there was one row for each department after the outer join in the temporary table.

Answer (score 2):

Use `left join` instead fo `natural join`.

```
select deptno, dname, loc, count(deptno) empcount, round(coalesce(avg(sal), 0),2) avgsal
from dept left join emp
group by deptno, dname, loc
```

Comment: oh, yes thanks! using(deptno) is missing and now the count function returns 1 if there is no emp in the dept, because there's one row in the temporary table with the left join... any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

```
select deptno, dname, loc, count(deptno) empcount, round(avg(sal),2) avgsal
from dept 
LEFT join emp
group by deptno, dname, loc
```

Is this what you are looking at? Check the output...

Answer (score 2):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljnaturaljoin.html you can do an outer natural join like so:

```
The following example is similar to the one above, but it also preserves
unmatched rows from the first (left) table:

SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES NATURAL LEFT JOIN CITIES
```

So you would do:

```
select deptno, dname, loc, count(deptno) empcount, round(avg(sal),2) avgsal
from dept natural left join emp
group by deptno, dname, loc
```